# Increase maximum amount of characters for entity reference field (tag style)

Tags: entities, 9

I have a Drupal 9 installation running Commerce 2. My products use a taxonomy entity reference field (tag style). There's one products category, where I need to have more references in the tag input field than currently allowed (1024 characters).

I looked it up and found a similar post where someone suggested to write a module to increase the maximum input value like so:

```
function MODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {

  if ($context['widget']->getPluginId() == 'entity_reference_autocomplete_tags') {
    if ($element['target_id']['#maxlength'] == 1024) {
      $element['target_id']['#maxlength'] = 3072;
    }
  }
}
```

So I did that, but it still doesn't let me input more than 1024 characters. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You may want to look at changing that field to a select list and using something like [Chosen](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen) to emulate an autocomplete experience. Even if you can add more tags into the autocomplete field, it's going to be a bad experience for editors.

Comment: @sonfd Yeah, I thought about that too. But sorrily this field references to a list of taxonomy terms which holds like 500+ values. So it will be a pain to edit it anyways :(

Comment: Apparently, it should work, I tried the same logic but used `hook_field_widget_single_element_form_alter` instead to make it work in D10.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to increase the maxlength of the input, but installed ["Autocomplete deluxe"](https://www.drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe) module, which implements the widget input field via jQuery chosen. Now I can set as many values as I like.